# How to continue running the script inside the new shell that has been called from the same script?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, register-transfer-level, cadence

I am a super newbie in this area so I apologize in advance for any dumb thing I might say! :D

I work with Cadence's RTL Compiler and I am trying to automate the process of synthesizing so many designs with different sizes located in different directories, and producing the reports and save them in each folder. I am using tcl scripts to run the commands of the RTL program inside Linux terminal.

First, I have to do some initializations outside the RTL environment. So I have created a script file called **setup.tcl** that I call from the Linux terminal and then call the RTL program itself (*rc*):

```
source setup.tcl
rc
```

This will run the RTL compiler program inside the same terminal so now the compiler commands can be entered.

```
rc:/>
```

Now, I need a script for the RTL commands named **rtl_script.tcl** to run all the commands inside RTL environment and it will work just fine doing:

```
rc:/>source rtl_script.tcl
```

I need to run the *whole routine* with just one command so that I can loop it and everything.

More precisely, a master script called **master.tcl** is needed that first runs the **setup.tcl**, opens RTL Compiler, and then runs **rtl_script.tcl** inside the rc environment. All done in the same terminal. Something like:

```
source setup.tcl
rc
source rtl_script.tcl
```

The problem is that when I enter the command *source master.tcl* the shell stops after entering the RTL environment and it does not run the **rtl_script.tcl**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give `rc` a script to run on the command line? Like `rc rtl_script.tcl` perhaps?

Comment: Further explanation on the title: I suppose running *rc* command will start a new shell inside the same terminal. So by *new shell* I mean after opening RTL Compiler and by the **script** I mean **master.tcl**.

Comment: Yes, I understood. The problem here is the same as people asking about how to run commands *inside* the remote shell they get from running `ssh` and the answer is use `ssh ... <commands to run>` so I was asking if `rc` can do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the over explanation, @Ethan. I have tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: If you can't get it to do it automatically in any way then you are probably going to need to look at using something like `expect` to automate it.

Comment: @EtanReisner I found the solution and your first comment gave me a great direction to do so. Thank you so much! Sorry for misspelling your name earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question and I thought the answer should have something to do with different shells. But all I had to do, as @EtanReisner told me, was to give `rc` command a script to run from but the correct syntax is like this:

```
rc -file rtl_script.tcl
```

If you want your master script to continue after running after `rc` finishes, you have to have an `exit` command at the end of `rtl_script.tcl` script.
I had to take a closer look at the Cadence documentation.